# SSRS Expression how to compare value from two different datasets?

Tags: reporting-services

So I've searched for this specifically but cannot find an example or answer anywhere.

I'm trying to compare a value of one dataset to the value of another dataset but it's not working.

Here's my expression:

`=IIF((Fields!IC_ADV.Value + Fields!OC_ADV.Value) > 0, Max(Fields!AMOUNT.Value, "Data_bucket_info") > 15, nothing)`

All I get is "True".  If I remove the '> 15' then I get a value but it's not the right value.  I've tried replacing Max with First, Min, Sum; without the '>15' I again get a value but not the right one and with the '>15' I get "True" or "False".

If I have Max in, I'm expecting to get the Max value for AMOUNT for all amount > 15; if I have Min in, I'm expecting to get the Min value for AMOUNT for all amount > 15.

So for example:

AMOUNT is in increments of 5; so 5, 10, 15, 20, 25....etc.

If (Fields!IC_ADV.Value + Fields!OC_ADV.Value) = 24 then what I want is for AMOUNT to display 25.  If (Fields!IC_ADV.Value + Fields!OC_ADV.Value) = 3 then I want AMOUNT to display 5.

The warning I keep getting in SSRS is 'The Value expression for the textrun 'Textbox12.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' uses a numeric aggregate function on data that is not numeric.  Numeric aggregate functions (Sum, Avg, StDev, Var, StDevP, and VarP) can only aggregate numeric data.'

But the AMOUNT field is a numeric value.

Comment: are you creating calculated field ??

Answer (score 0):

It is not lot clear from your description what you are trying to achieve. But for what I understand you want to match the sum of `IC_ADV` and `OC_ADV` with some value and depending on that you want to get the value. for that you can set the expression as below,

```
=IIF((Fields!IC_ADV.Value + Fields!OC_ADV.Value) = 24,Max(Fields!AMOUNT.Value, "Data_bucket_info"),IIF((Fields!IC_ADV.Value + Fields!OC_ADV.Value) = 3,Min(Fields!AMOUNT.Value, "Data_bucket_info"),Nothing)
```

But if you want to match match value of one dataset to another datasets value based on some common field then you should take a look at the `LookUp`. [Here is more info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, I think it's better to make it in Math way. Try the expression below:

=((Fields!IC_ADV.Value + Fields!OC_ADV.Value)\5+1)*5